# Unzipping files in unattended mode

Tags: zip

When I use the unzip command from Linux machine and the files under ZIP already exists on my local directory, I get the interactive question: (if I want to replace the files from the ZIP with the existing files on my Linux machine

How to use the unzip command without this interactive question?

```
 [@superuser]# ls -ltr

 total 0
 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root            0 Nov 15 15:13 all_my_files1
 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root            0 Nov 15 15:13 all_my_files2

[@superuser]# unzip MY_FILES.zip

    Archive:  MY_FILES.zip
    replace all_my_files1.txt? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: A
        inflating: all_my_files1.txt  
        inflating: all_my_files2.txt
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As the `unzip(1l)` man page states, pass `-o` to `unzip` in order to force overwriting of existing files without prompting.

Comment: Caveat: a zip comment will prompt you to press Q or any other key to proceed and hang execution. The only way I came up with to avoid it is to pass `-q` but this will also cause unzip to not show the list of files being unzipped.

Answer (score 10):

You want the `-o` option:

```
unzip -o MY_FILES.zip
```

[Source](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/unzip.1.asp)

> overwrites existing files without prompting. This is a dangerous option, so use it with care. (It is often used with **-f**, however.)

Comment: For people feeling scared, I think it's fair to say it really depends on what you're unzipping when overwriting files. In my case, `iCloud Photos.zip` isn't a disaster if I lose the odd photo. But I wonder what danger there is beyond overwriting identically named files (which you'd hope is not that common).